# Mongorito: save(...).then is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried something similar to the example given on the [readme.md](https://github.com/vdemedes/mongorito/blob/master/Readme.md) file:

```
var Mongorito = require('mongorito');
var Model = Mongorito.Model;

Mongorito.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cr-test');

class User extends Model {
  collection() {
    return 'users';
  }
}

var user1 = new User({
  name: "James Gosling",
  email: "user1@gmail.com",
  password: "changeme"
});

user1.save().then(() => {
  console.log('User Created');
});
```

when I run `node --harmony server.js` I get this error:

```
user1.save().then(() => {
             ^

TypeError: user1.save(...).then is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\app\server.js:24:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3
```

Could someone explain me how could I fix that?

Comment: What version of node are you on? `node -v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme on GitHub is outdated, the [project's website](http://mongorito.com/) now states:

> MongoDB ODM for Node.js based on ES6 generators.
>
> No callbacks or promises.

It uses generators, which can find an example of on the [getting started](http://mongorito.com/guides/getting-started/) page:

```
'use strict';

function* saveUser () {
  var user1 = new User({
    name: "James Gosling",
    email: "user1@gmail.com",
    password: "changeme"
  });

  yield user1.save();
}
```

In order for generators to work, you must use `'use strict;'` and the `function*` syntax. This [GitHub project](https://github.com/JustinDrake/node-es6-examples#generators) has additional examples.

Also, starting with Node v4, you no longer need the `--harmony` ([now a synonym of `--es_staging`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/#i-have-my-infrastructure-set-up-to-leverage-the-harmony-flag-should-i-remove-it)) flag for generators.

Comment: Hi, I tried it as well (before try the Github) and I got an error using `yield`. Someting like: " Unexpected strict mode reserved word".

Comment: Add `'use strict';` at the top of the file

Comment: `yield user1.save();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:430:10)
    at startup (node.js:141:18)
    at node.js:980:3`

Comment: Do you use the function*() syntax? https://github.com/JustinDrake/node-es6-examples#generators

Comment: I just added it and it is working right now. Thank you so much to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

or you can do like this also ... but here you can execute just a single statement

```
user1.save().then(savedUser => console.log(`saved user: ${savedUser}`));
```